# Percentage Root Mean Square for Big Differences in r

Tags: r, percentage

The function for percentage root mean square is as below:

```r
prmse <- function (y_true, y_pred) {
    percent_rmse <- sqrt(mean( ((y_true - y_pred)/(y_true)) **2))*100
    return(percent_rmse)
}
```

When the difference between predicted and true labels are small the resulting prmse is between 0 and 100 but when the difference is big the resulting value is not between 0 and 100. What can be modified  in the code to get a resulting value between 0 and 100.

```r
# Resulting value between 0 and 100
prmse(c(10,15,22),c(20,30,35))

# Resulting value not between 0 and 100
prmse(c(10,10,10),c(1000,10,10))
```

Comment: If the rmse is not between 0 and 100, that's an empirical result. You can't just change the formula to compute a coefficient just because the number of digits of the result bug you, personally.

Comment: @MartinWettstein bu this is supposed to be percentage rmse. I want to get a percentage out of this metric. Isn't it supposed to yield a percentage? My issue is here is that I was wondering what modifications can be done to the formula I provided to get a percentage as the performance metric's name suggests.

Comment: Yes, but a percentage may well be above 100 if your deviation exceeds the range of the true values by several magnitudes as in your example.

Comment: @MartinWettstein That made sense. So you are saying that when the metric yields a result like 5000 I should interpret as 5000 times error?

Comment: No, that would be an error that exceeds the range of the true values by a factor of 50. So, a 50 times error. That means that your prediction is not really good. But that seems to have been the objective of this ficticious data.